# Load data when click on button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-scope, angular-controller

I am searching how to call a function from a controller with parameters in textbox.
This is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controllerInput.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="appName">
    <input type="text" id="idName" name="idName" ng-model="modelName" ng-controller="controllerName">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="functionName()">Execute</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

This is the controller :

```
d3DemoApp.controller('controllerName',function($rootScope,$scope) {
    $scope.modelName = '';
    $scope.functionName = function () {
        myFunction($scope.modelName);
    };
});
```

And app.js :

```
function myFunction(concatURL){
    //loadData('URL' + concatURL);
    console.log("Function successfully called !");
}
```

The problem is on my app file, I have a function loadData which must be call but it is in a controller named controllerApp and my function myFunction is not know if it is in controllerApp.
Hope you will can help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Why dont you create a service for your function and call it from the controller?

Comment: Did you check your console? There are javascript errors `Uncaught ReferenceError: d3DemoApp is not defined`

Comment: @Jamiec, yes I thought to do that but the code which must be executed is in app.js.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/PtLeM7ynNbsKMNfLwIb0?p=preview pls go through this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made two mistakes in your code

1. You have not declared the module `appName` before trying to use it.
2. You have applied the `ng-controller` just to the input element, not to the element containing both the input and the button.

---

To fix the first you need this line before trying to use the module:

```
var variableName = angular.module("appName",[]);
```

---

To fix the second, move the `ng-controller` element up:

```
<body ng-app="appName" ng-controller="controllerName">
    <input type="text" id="idName" name="idName" ng-model="modelName">
   <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="functionName()">Execute</button>
</body>
```

---

Comment: Thanks for your response, I edited my question because it doesn't solve my problem. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @afeffifari-1957 you need to go and read the anguular docs. This works by dependency injection, where one controller can rely on a service, and that service itself can rely on other injected services, This is all covered by the docs and is too broad to answer here.

Answer (score 0):

on JS file (controller) add this on the header

```
var d3DemoApp = angular.module('D3demoApp', []);
```

on html file, Try to wrap the controller into a div

```
<body ng-app="D3demoApp">
  <div ng-controller="controllerFilterSearch">
    <input type="text" id="searchTextBox" name="searchTextBox" ng-model="searchText">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getSearchText()">Rechercher</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: what is the error. I edit live on your plunkr, it does work.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I edited my question because it doesn't solve my problem. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code , pls go through this

```
<body ng-app="mainApp" >
    <div ng-controller="controllerFilterSearch">
        <input type="text" id="searchTextBox" name="searchTextBox" ng-model="searchText" >
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getSearchText()">Rechercher</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
var d3DemoApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

d3DemoApp.controller('controllerFilterSearch',function($rootScope,$scope) {
    $scope.searchText = '';
    $scope.getSearchText = function () {
        alert();
        myFunction($scope.searchText);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I edited my question because it doesn't solve my problem. Thanks a lot !